# match datastamp multiple variations with zerofill, without etc

Tags: php, regex

I need to match a variety of datestamps in a text string

## pattern with zerofill in day/month

```
$date_day_pattern = '0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]';
$date_month_pattern = '0[1-9]|1[0-2]';
$date_year_pattern = '[12][0-9]|20[12][0-9]';

$date_pattern = "(?<!\d)($date_day_pattern)[^\d]?($date_month_pattern)[^\d]?($date_year_pattern)(?!\d)";
preg_match("/$date_pattern/m", $input, $matches);
```

This works when matching for

```
01-05-2015
01-05-15
01052015
010515
```

But I also need to match for datestamps where day/month doesn't have zerofill. But then the datestamp must have a seperator between day, month and year

```
1-5-2015
```

The pattern must **not** match

```
152015
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an additional alternative to the first two expressions:

- For the day pattern: `[1-9](?=\D)`
- For the month pattern: `(?<=\D)[1-9](?=\D)`

This will become:

```
$date_day_pattern = '0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[1-9](?=\D)';
$date_month_pattern = '0[1-9]|1[0-2]|(?<=\D)[1-9](?=\D)';
$date_year_pattern = '[12][0-9]|20[12][0-9]';

$date_pattern = "(?<!\d)($date_day_pattern)\D?($date_month_pattern)\D?($date_year_pattern)(?!\d)";
```

The above will even match weird, but non-ambiguous strings like:

```
2-0116
```

... but it will not allow:

```
201-16
```

Note that `\D` is equivalent to `[^\d]`.

Comment: so `(?=)` is some kind of lookahead?

Comment: and the same with `(?<=)` a look behind?

Comment: Indeed, you pinned it: positive look ahead and look behind.

Comment: It doesn't matter about the weird match.. Because the haystack comes from OCR and may already have some misinterpreted chars

Answer (score 1):

You can use [conditional subpattern feature](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.conditional.php) for this i.e. if leading `0` is matched then make separator optional otherwise make it mandatory.

```
$date_pattern = 
'(?<!\d)((0)?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(?(2)\D?|\D)(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(?(2)\D?|\D)([12][0-9]|20[12][0-9])(?!\d)';
```

- Optional Captured group 2 is `(0)?`
- `(?(2)\D?|\D)` makes `\D` optional if group #2 is matched otherwise `\D` (non-digit) is required.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wK8kN1/1)